# Why does write.csv transform 4 columns to 1 column in R shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, shiny, printing

I am currently working on a project using in which I need to import an export a data frame as a .csv file. Here is the code:

**ui.R**

```
fileInput(
  "file1",
  "Importer depuis un fichier",
  accept = c(
    "text/csv",
    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
    ".csv")
),
rHandsontableOutput("tabl")
downloadButton(
  "imprCsv",
  "Imprimer en CSV"
)
```

**server.R**

```
reactDataBase <- reactiveValues(data = dataBase)
output$tabl <- renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(reactDataBase$data, useTypes = TRUE, stretchH = "all") %>%
  hot_col("Pièce", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
  hot_col("Désignation", readOnly = TRUE)
})

observe({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(is.null(inFile)) {return(NULL)}
  reactDataBase$data<<-read.table(file=inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=";", na.string="")
})

output$imprCsv <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {paste0("Rapport ", str_replace_all(Sys.time(), ":", "_"), ".csv")},
  content = function(file) {
    print(reactDataBase$data)
    write.csv(reactDataBase$data, file)
  }
)
```

The problem, here is that the csv file isn't of type

```
    Piece   Name   Value   Minim
1   P2      Picj   12      TRUE
2   P5      Picj   23      TRUE
3   P6      Picj   11      TRUE
4   C15     Calg   9       TRUE
5   X34     Xanol  878     TRUE
```

But it looks more like:

```
,"Piece","Name","Value","Minim"
1,"P2","Picj","12","TRUE"
2,"P5","Picj","23","TRUE"
3,"P6","Picj","11","TRUE"
4,"C15","Calg","9","TRUE"
5,"X34","Xanol","878","TRUE"
```

Any solution?

Comment: The left-justification of `Value` makes me think its type is numeric rather than character.  The same may be true of `Minim`.  The default value of the `quote` argument to `write.csv` is `TRUE`.  So the behaviour may well be as expected.  To check, we need to see the types of the columns in `reactDatabase$data`.  Which you haven't given us.

Comment: Thank you first for your help @Limey. The types in `reactDataBase$data` isn't important bc I put some random values in this example. The thing is that it regroups every information from a line into a character string to put in in one column. My `reactDataBase$data` is a perfect dataframe like in the first tab I showed you, so I think the problem comes from `write.csv`.  Tell me if you understand right what I am trying to tell to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

I just used `write.csv2` instead of `write.csv`